# Percent Calculation in Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-quicksight

I want to calculate percent based on count of events. Basically, I want to calculate successful login attempts on a website. Something like below
count(successful_attempts)/count(total_attempts)

successful_attempts and total_attempts are recorded as events in login_attempts column.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly 2 approaches to your problem.

**Compute the percentage yourself:**

You can [add a calculated field](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/adding-a-calculated-field-analysis.html) to your analysis or your dataset and use the a similar formula to the one you mentioned.
You might need to use *sum* rather than *count* depending on the type of your login_attemps column.
You'll then be able to see that value using a simple [KPI chart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/kpi.html)

**Use charts to make the computation:**

You could use a [gauge chart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/gauge-chart.html).
Using the *sum of successful attempts* as value and *sum of attempts* as target. The chart will compute the percentages itself.
[Donut charts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/donut-chart.html) and [Pie charts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/pie-chart.html) will work in a similar fashion.

Finally, [horizontal or vertical stacked 100% bar charts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/bar-charts.html) might be another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try percentOfTotal http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/percentOfTotal-function.html
(I do not have much context to provide an example, but the documentation should help)